# What's wrong with this implementation of quicksort?

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quicksort algorithm choosing the pivot as the rightmost element as described in Cormey et al., *Introduction to Algorithms*:

[image]

Here is my Python implementation:

```
def partition(A, p, r):
    pivot = A[r]
    i = p - 1
    for j in range(p, r-1):
        if A[j] < pivot:
            i += 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    A[i+1], A[r] = A[r], A[i+1]
    return i+1

def quicksort(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        quicksort(A, p, q-1)
        quicksort(A, q+1, r)
```

However, if I try to test it like so:

```
A = [2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4]
quicksort(A, 0, len(A)-1)
print(A)
```

I get an array which is not sorted but just partitioned once:

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6]
```

(That is, all the elements left (right) of the `4` are smaller (greater) than it). It seems that the recursive calls to `quicksort` are not operating in place on the input array `A` like the call to `partition`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is in `partition`, exactly in `for j in range(p, r-1):` :
It must be, `for j in range(p, r):`.
 This happens because in Python, the stop index is not included in the range, but the algorithm meant to include `r-1`, therefore one must stop at `r` in order to include `r-1`.